# Unable to read the value of a document - Firestore

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection which saves totals **datewise**.

Name of collection is `scan_total_dtwise` , name of document is company's name, for example `Patrol 1`. In this document I am setting records datewise, see pic below:

[image]

If `Doc` does not exist, I am able to create it and assign it number 1, using below code:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("scan_total_dtwise").doc(this.splitted_1).set({
  [this.show_year_month_date] : 1,
```

But if it exists, I am not able to update it, because I dont know how to access `incDoc.data().4-AUG-2020`.

How do I access `console.log(incDoc.data().date_doc_to_update);` as it is coming **undefined**. See image below `console.log("Document data:", doc.data());`:

```
update_exisiting_serial_total(){
  var date_doc_to_update = this.show_year_month_date
  var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('scan_total_dtwise').doc(this.splitted_1);
  firebase.firestore().runTransaction(transaction=> {
    return transaction.get(docRef).then(incDoc=> { 
        //if no value exist, assume it as 0 and increase to 1
        console.log(incDoc.data().date_doc_to_update);
        var newIncId = (incDoc.data().date_doc_to_update || 0) + 1;
        transaction.update(docRef, { [this.show_year_month_date]: newIncId });
        return newIncId;
        ...//more code
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access an object property using a variable, you should use JavaScript's bracket notation to index into the object:

```
incDoc.data()[date_doc_to_update]
```

Or to put in more clearly, IMO:

```
const data = incDoc.data();
value = data[date_doc_to_update];
```